# stm32 factory bootloader possibly overwritten with openocd?

Tags: stm32, openocd

tl;dr: flashed firmware to 0x00000000 instead of 0x08000000, am I lost?

Hello,

my device is based on a STM32F103CBTx which came with a proprietary firmware and had readout protection on.
I connect to it with a ST-Link v2 SWDIO and SWCLK connected to PA13 and PA14 and this command:

```
sudo openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg
```

I don't remember how I removed flash protection, but it worked as the original firmware didn't work anymore. Then I created a simple hello world firmware which pulls up and down three gpios and flashed it. The gpios are pulled up and down in 700ms intervals.

After flashing, I can't connect with openocd anymore. I forgot to specify the offset, the manual says the offset defaults to 0 and as it worked, I suppose instead of the boot loader my shitty hello world is pulling up and down some random pins happily… Is this possible? All other threads I found say the boot loader is write protected.

This is the last contact I had:

```
> halt
halt
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Handler HardFault
xPSR: 0x01000003 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xffffffdc
> flash write_image erase fw.hex
flash write_image erase fw.hex
auto erase enabled
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Handler HardFault
xPSR: 0x61000003 pc: 0x2000003a msp: 0xffffffdc
wrote 4096 bytes from file fw.hex in 0.285697s (14.001 KiB/s)
> reset
reset
jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f1x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
```

Any directions highly appreciated.

Edit:
What I get now, also tried another st-link:

```
%  sudo openocd -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f /usr/share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg 
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select '.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v17 API v2 SWIM v4 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.244356
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> flashed firmware to 0x00000000 instead of 0x08000000, am I lost?

No, it doesn't matter at all, they are the same.

After reset, the MCU loads the word at address `0` in `SP`, and the next one at address `4` in `PC`. The `BOOT0` and `BOOT1` pins control which memory gets mapped to `0x00000000`. Usually, `BOOT0` is tied low, and flash memory at `0x08000000` gets mirrored at `0x00000000`.

> instead of the boot loader my shitty hello world is pulling up and down some random pins happily… Is this possible? All other threads I found say the boot loader is write protected.

The factory bootloader is indeed write protected, openocd can't overwrite it.

However, your application could have reconfigured the `SWD` pins, by writing a wrong value in `GPIOA->CRH` or `AFIO->MAPR`, thereby preventing openocd from working. It's the most common cause of this problem.

Fortunately, there is a way to recover.

**Connect under Reset**

If the reset pin of the controller is held low for a while when openocd is started, the application is prevented from starting, and messing up the GPIO configuration.

Openocd can do this automatically, when

- It's told to do so, the line `reset_config srst_only srst_nogate` is present somewhere in the configuration script.
- The MCU reset pin is connected to the debugger hardware, pin 15 on an official ST-Link/V2.

Or you can do it manually, by whatever means your board provides. If you are lucky, it has a reset button, if not, you must find a way to somehow ground the MCU reset pin.

- Pull the reset pin low
- Start openocd
- Wait until the `Info : Target voltage` line appears. Maybe a second longer.
- Release the reset pin.

It requires a bit of trial and error, you'll get better with practice.

Then you can flash your improved application, which carefully avoids reconfiguring the SWD pins.

Comment: I had to keep the reset pin pulled down, connect openocd, enter `reset halt`, and then release the pin within a second to be able to erase the flash. Otherwise the target couldn't be halted or openocd lost connection. Now I could flash my new hello-world with correct SWD pin configuration. Thanks a lot for the clarification!